# find out programmatically which Ubuntu release are supported

Tags: support

Is there a programmatic way for finding out which Ubuntu releases are currently supported by upstream?  Something like an HTTP(s) service that returns

```
$ curl https://get_supported_ubuntu_versions.com?q=all
xenial zesty artful
```

perhaps?

Comment: can you please give an example for the required output for a specific case?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need something like this `curl http://releases.ubuntu.com/ | grep "The following releases of Ubuntu are available" -A 6 | gawk -F\> '{print $3}' | gawk -F\< '{print $1}' | grep -v '^$'`. Currently its output lists following releases:

- Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus)
- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (Trusty Tahr)
- Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise Pangolin)

Maybe it looks not very professional but it works for your question, I think.